# Android Studio 3.6, cannot install app on device

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I have a Honor 20, which I used until two days ago to debug the app on device, which was going smoothly enough. From today it just won't install anymore. After correctly connecting and detecting the device, the Run tab says:

```
04/22 11:54:38: Launching 'app' on HUAWEI YAL-L21.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'device 'NXEDU19B01001505' not found'
```

The build goes smoothly. It disconnects the device upon launching it.
It works just fine on the emulator.

minSdk 28, compile and target 29.

Some days ago I updated the phone to Android 10.0 (apparently, while having v9.0 it was running just fine).

USB debugging is of course active since some time.

Comment: Did you try to revoke USB debugging authorisations to get a new prompt?

Comment: seems working, I will confirm in a while

Comment: @romulus if you make it an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Try to revoke USB debugging authorisations to get a new prompt for authorisation.

Comment: I tried to revoke again, clean cache, restart, restart the pc, restart the phone, nothing works

Comment: Did you try with another cable? Different USB ports?